# How can i pass parameter via url while clicking href link in phonegap?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to pass a parameter between two pages in PhoneGap

```
$('.left_menu').append('<ul>'+
        '<li><a href="A.html?username="+employeecode+"&role="+rolecode+"" rel="external">A</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="B.html?username="+employeecode+"&role="+rolecode+"" rel="external">B</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="C.html?username="+employeecode+"&role="+rolecode+"" rel="external">C</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="D.html?username="+employeecode+"&role="+rolecode+"" rel="external">D</a></li>'+
    '</ul>');
```

In `A.html` page for get the parameter I used the following code:

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
    var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
    if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
        return KeyValuePair[1];
    }//END IF
 }//END FOR
}//END FUNCTION

var employeecode = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('username'));
var rolecode = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('role'));
```

Comment: What error you get from above code?

Comment: this is not error this code not working nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

You can add following code for set url and get url parameter value.

```
$('.left_menu').append('<ul>'+
    '<li><a href="A.html?username="'+employeecode+'&role='+rolecode+'" rel="external">A</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="B.html?username="'+employeecode+'&role='+rolecode+'" rel="external">B</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="C.html?username="'+employeecode+'&role='+rolecode+'" rel="external">C</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="D.html?username="'+employeecode+'&role='+rolecode+'" rel="external">D</a></li>'+
'</ul>');
```

**In A.html page**

```
/** GET PARAMETER **/
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

var username = getParameterByName('username');
var role = getParameterByName('role');
```