# How to pass parameters in android phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

For the first time i am trying my hand On Android Phonegap application.For the same i am designing a sample application where i have to pass some parameters from one `HTML` page to another .Here is the HTML for my first page ..

```
<div class="choice_list"> 
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
<li><a href="empdetails.html" data-transition="slidedown"> <img src="images/will.jpg"/> <h3> Will Smith </h3></a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Now as per my requirement i have to pass the `<h3>` parameter to my next HTML page i.e `empdetails.html` and display it there as soon as the link button gets clicked..

Here is my `empdetails.html` HTML..

```
<div id="header2">
    <h2>Name: "I need to show name here"</h2>
</div>
```

Please help me to get this ..I am very new in this ..
Thanks ..

Comment: have you tried to pass it using url parameter?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I am not aware of it ..How can it be achieved ?

Comment: You can use pages and load that pages in one file (index.html).

Comment: You can do with localStorage as @Tarun suggested OR you can do by this way also, see link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986752/how-can-i-pass-parameter-via-url-while-clicking-href-link-in-phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage in phonegap (set on first page)

```
  window.localStorage.setItem("key", $("h3").text());
```

For get the local storage use(set on second page)

```
var data=window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: OK..Can i use this code if the data in `h3` is coming dynamically from the database..Will it Work ? Also for using this code Do i need to add <script type="text/javascript"> on both the pages and put these code line in between that?

Comment: yes,you have to add this code in script tag.If this solved your problem please tick as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Local Storage is the solution, you can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).