# How to pass parameters to web service URL from Phonegap HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web-services, cordova

I have a HTML page that i am using in Phone Gap application .Now as per my requirement i have to pass the values present into this web page like `name` , `name` etc to Webservice URL but i have no idea where i can write the code and what to do to call a webservice URL..

Here is my HTML ..

```
<div id="header2">
    <h2 id ="name">Name: Will Smith</h2>
</div>

<div id="header2">
    <h2 id ="contact">Contact Details: +91-86044</h2>
</div>

<div id="header2">
    <h2 id ="department">Department: Software Support</h2>
</div>

<div id="header2">
    <h2 id ="location">Location: INDIA</h2>
</div>

<br/>

<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; background-color: green;">
<button id="call" class="button">Call</button>
</div>
```

Please help me to pass these values into webservice..
Thanks..

Update..
I am trying this code but no success

```
<script>
// PhoneGap event
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods 
//
function onDeviceReady()
{
     $('#call').click(function(){
    var name=$("#name").text();
    alert(name);
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. YOu have already asked the same question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988826/how-to-pass-parameters-in-android-phonegap-application)

Comment: @frank Can i use Document.ready function in phonegap

Comment: @frank Please see my updated post and code and tell me why i am not getting an alert on the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google chrome provides a tool called REST CONSOLE for passing parameters to your webservice, you can access this tool from the following link

```
chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/index.html
```

REST console will handles the response generated from your webservice, just pass your webservice url, parameters to it and test your webservice.

Comment: Please see my updated post and code and tell me why i am not getting an alert on button click ,,

Comment: may be you forget to include the jquery.js file

Comment: I have the jquery.js file.Is the syntax all right ..I dont know because i am for the first time working on this ..Please tell me

Comment: include jquery.js file on top of all the included js files.

Comment: It is On top only ..I have to say one thing ..i am testing this on browser not on Phone device may be this is the issue or anything else sir ?

Comment: check the click event syntax given in the link

Comment: Please see my synatx in the post ..its all correct ..then why i am not able to get the alert

Comment: @jcesarmobile Now i have commented that method and added `$(document).ready(function()` still i am not able to get any alert .Why ?